# Reply buttons not showing in telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyrogram

I use pyrogram for my bot

I want to send a messages with buttons:

```
from pyrogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton,ReplyKeyboardMarkup
from pyrogram import types

def cmd_start(self, chat_id, message):
    with Client("my_acc", api_id=self.api_id,api_hash=self.api_hash,proxy=self.proxy) as app:
            
        start_service = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='but1', callback_data='service')
        start_system = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='but2', callback_data='system')
        start_check = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='but3', callback_data='check')
        start_other = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='but4', callback_data='other')
        start_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[[start_service, start_system], [start_check, start_other]])
        
        app.send_message(chat_id, 'test', reply_markup=start_keyboard)
```

The sending is successfull, but I see only simple text message 'test' in the chat instead of 4 buttons

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` for inline keyboards - use [`InlineKeyboardMarkup`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/types/InlineKeyboardMarkup#pyrogram.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup) instead.

Do something like this:

```
start_service = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='but1', callback_data='service')
start_system = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='but2', callback_data='system')
start_check = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='but3', callback_data='check')
start_other = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='but4', callback_data='other')

start_keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[[start_service, start_system], [start_check, start_other]])
        
app.send_message(chat_id, 'test', reply_markup=start_keyboard)
```

Answer (score 0):

inline keyboard can be send only by a Bot! you should set `bot_token=<token>` in `kwargs` of `Client`